# Accessing Property in master page from InitializeCulture prevents controls from being created

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have been working on localization and want to put the language into the Viewstate to access in a user control.

I have a test project I set up to show the problem. On the user control, I have only one label.

If I don't access the Master pages viewstate (where that line is commented out), all works well and the label is created.

If I access the viewstate to get the language from the viewstate, I get an object not found error and the object will be null. The error is:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The variable "culture" does get the string from the Viewstate.

If I comment out the line with the master page access, "culture" is set and everything works fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Globalization;

namespace TestCulture
{
    public partial class Sample : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected override void InitializeCulture()
        {
            string culture;
            culture = "en-US";
            culture = "es-MX";
            culture = ((TestCulture.Site1)Page.Master).zCulture;

            base.InitializeCulture();
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTestLabel.Text = ((TestCulture.Site1)Page.Master).Name;
        }

    }
}
```

And the Master page is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace TestCulture
{
    public partial class Site1 : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        public string zCulture
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["ocCulture"] == null) 
                    ViewState["ocCulture"] = "en-US";
                return (string)ViewState["ocCulture"];
            }
            set { ViewState["ocCulture"] = value; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                if (ViewState["Name"] == null) 
                    ViewState["Name"] = "Tom";
                return (string)ViewState["Name"];
            }
            set { ViewState["ocCulture"] = value; }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Actually, if you access the property on the master page from "InitializeCulture", it won't create the controls.

You can access property from the Page_Load and Page_Init events without any affects.

Why does accessing the property cause the controls not to be created?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Because the code is crashing?

Comment: The problem already occurs when accessing only the Page.Master property in InitializeCulture overriden method (e.g. MasterPage mp = Master;).

Answer (score 0):

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

You reference to null. You return either "en-US" or String.null.

```
if (ViewState["ocCulture"] == null) 
   ViewState["ocCulture"] = "en-US";
return (string)ViewState["ocCulture"];
```

Try this:

```
if (ViewState["ocCulture"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["ocCulture"] = "en-US";
        }
        else 
       { 
          ViewState["ocCulture"] = "";
       }
return (string)ViewState["ocCulture"];
```